# How to automaticly restart a CLI program when it stops logging?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a CLI program that stops working from time to time.
When it stops working, it would stop logging.
Is there any way to restart it automatically  when it stops logging?
It won't become unresponsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableExtensions

%:^)
start "" /b /d "C:\Path\To\Folder\Program" "The_Program.exe"

%:^(
%__AppDir__%TimeOut.exe 30 /nobreak|echo\Waiting....

for %%i in ("C:\Full\Path\To\File.log"
    )do if "%_log%" == "" (set "_log=%%~si" && goto %:^(
    )else if not "%%~si" == "%_log%" (set "_log=%%~si" && goto %:^( 
    )else %__AppDir__%TaskKill.exe /f /im "The_Program.exe" /t >nul 2>&1

%:^/
%__AppDir__%TimeOut.exe /t 10 /nobreak|echo\Restarting... & (
%__AppDir__%TaskList.exe /v /fo csv /nh|%__AppDir__%find.exe/i "The_Program.exe"
   )  >nul 2>&1 && goto %:^/ || goto %:^)
```

---

Use a for loop to monitor file size changes, when changes no longer occur, kill the process, wait a few seconds, and restart